# is there a difference in meaning between the terms "bone architecture" and "bone structure"?

Tags: human-biology, human-anatomy, bone-biology

I'm wondering whether "bone architecture" and "bone structure" mean the same thing, or whether they refer to two different concepts.

In this article - http://rheumatology.oxfordjournals.org/content/48/suppl_4/iv3.full - *bone microstructure* and *bone microarchitecture* are mentioned in the abstract in a way which makes them sound like they are the same thing. Also, they seem to be used as synonyms in the rest of the article.

This website - http://www.doitpoms.ac.uk/tlplib/bones/structure.php - discusses cortical vs cancellous bone under "*structure* and composition of bone" while other sites often discuss the same thing under the heading "bone *architecture*".

So am I right in thinking that the architecture of bones and the structure of bones are synonyms and that either term can be used when referring to osteoporosis? Thanks.